# Unusual “Illegal Forward Referance” Java Compile (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, javac

I'm developing a program on Android Studio that works right now.
But after I got rid of

> "error: illegal forward reference"

I can not compile the program again.

[build window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCTao.png)

API.java

```
package com.karabama.service.apiservice;
// Created by Majid Arabi on 12/16/2018.

import com.karabama.service.app.G;
import com.karabama.service.model.pay.Ports;
                                // ^error: illegal forward reference

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;


public class API {
    public interface V1 {

    @GET(G.API_URL_V1 + "/ports")
    Call<Ports> getPorts();

    }

    public interface V2 {

    }
}
```

Project build.gradle :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module app: build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle- 
    plugin:0.11.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.one_developer.karabama.service"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 141
        versionName "@string/app_version_name"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id:"my_id",onesignal_google_project_number:"my_project_number"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Android Studio 3.2.1 .Use OpenJDK: v8 by default studio. I even installed JDK Version 1.8.0.192. But I'm still making mistakes

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: why you add the `buildscript` twice? also `com.google.code.gson` is added twice. and that `G.API_URL_V1` is non-sense; because no host-name is required.

Comment: Thank you @MartinZeitler . According to your comment, I am removed `buildscript` from app:build.gradle and moved to project:build.gradle and now project is running